# ping: ./ipsweep.sh.105: Name or service not known

Tags: linux, bash, debian

#Code:

```
#!/bin/bash
for ip in `seq 100 110`; do
    ping -c 1 $0.$ip | grep "64 bytes" | cut -d " " -f 4 | tr -d ":" &
done
```

#command:

```
./ipsweep.sh 192.168.0
```

#Result:

```
ping: ./ipsweep.sh.105: Name or service not known
```

Comment: Lets first get it clear what your intension is. Are you trying to ping IP range `192.168.0.100` up to `192.168.0.110` ?  If so,  you can use i.e: `for i in {100..110}; do ping -c1 192.168.0.$i; done`

Answer (score 4):

`$0` is the pathname of the script. `$1` is the first parameter.

The command you're generating is

```
ping -c 1 ./pingsweep.sh.100
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple script which does what you want. You can modify it to suite your needs

```
#!/bin/bash
        
ping_hosts () 
{ 
    network="192.168.0"
    start=$(date +"%d-%m-%Y-%T")
    local s=$1
    local e=$2
    printf '%s\n\n' "Pinging $network"
    for ((i=s; i<=e; i++))
    do
        if ping -s 64 -c 1 -W 1 ${network}.${i} >/dev/null; then
            ((count1 += 1))
            printf '%s\n' "${network}.${i} is UP"
        else
            ((count2 += 1))
            printf '%s\n' "${network}.${i} is DOWN"
        fi
    done
    end=$(date +"%d-%m-%Y-%T")
    printf '%s\n' "Start:$start"
    printf '%s\n\n' "End**:$end"
    printf '%s UP and %s DOWN\n' "$count1" "$count2"
}
if (($# < 2)); then
    printf '%s\n' "Use start and end range i.e:  .${0##*.} 100 110"
    exit 1
else
    ping_hosts $1 $2
fi
```

You can make the script executable by ie.

`chmod u+x ping_hosts`

If you run it without arguments, it yeilds:

```
$> ./ping_host 
Use start and end range i.e:  ./ping_host 100 110
```

If you run it as:

```
$> ./ping_host 100 110
Pinging 192.168.0

192.168.0.100 is UP
192.168.0.101 is DOWN
192.168.0.102 is UP
192.168.0.103 is DOWN
192.168.0.104 is UP
192.168.0.105 is DOWN
192.168.0.106 is DOWN
192.168.0.107 is DOWN
192.168.0.108 is DOWN
192.168.0.109 is DOWN
192.168.0.110 is DOWN
Start:24-08-2021-22:55:59
End**:24-08-2021-22:56:07

3 UP and 8 DOWN
```

Comment: could also just use `if ping -q -W1 -c1 86.50.48.14 > /dev/null; then ...`  (or switch to `fping` which might be a bit more easily scriptable)

Comment: @ilkkachu oh of course, that is even better! Updated and thanks for the pointer!